# why have a constructor called in the same class?

Tags: java

```
public class Store {
  // instance fields
  String productType;
  
  // constructor method
  public Store(String product) {
    productType = product;
  }
  
  // advertise method
  public void advertise() {
    String message = "Selling " + productType + "!";
        System.out.println(message);
  }
  
  // main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cookie = "Cookies";
    Store cookieShop = new Store(cookie);
    
    cookieShop.advertise();
  }
}
```

In this class, the constructor for the class is called in its own main method. Why wouldn't this recursively call itself infinitely?

---

**EDIT**: From the future, yes; this quite a noob question that could be, and has been solved by reading the docs.

Comment: Method `main(...)` is declared `static`. The constructor of a class is used to construct *instances* of this class, not the class itself. The class itself is loaded (and constructed) through the JMV (specifically, through the class loader).

Comment: It's not infinite recursion simply because the `Store` constructor doesn't call the `main` method.

Comment: technically `main` can run without ever creating any instance of `Store`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors of a class are used to construct class-*instances*. Static methods are methods of the class, not of its instances (although they can be accessed through its instances). A class is loaded through a [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). Most classes are loaded and constructed through the [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()), the JVM takes care of constructing the class.

The class `Store` is already loaded when `main(...)` is executed and the call to the constructor creates, as explained above, an instance of that class, not the class itself. Thus, no recursive calls occur.

As was pointed out by @AndyTurner, even if an instance method were to call a constructor, this would not necessarily lead to a recursion. The constructor constructs a *new* instance, the old instance is decouple from the new instance.

Comment: I would point out that there is no problem with having a constructor invocation even in an instance method. The problem comes somewhere that an unbounded recursion would occur, e.g. in a constructor or field initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Main method is a static method and it is called one time  when application is starting. Once application started, main method can't run again.

When you making a store object, It is true that constructor is running. But it does not calling main method again.